# Add a UINavigationBar and UIToolbar to modal UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm creating an app that has a similar layout as the Apple Contacts app. I have created a UITableViewController and embedded it in a UINavigationController using a Storyboard. I then have an add button that opens a UITableViewController in a modal view. I have added a top bar to this view using the storyboard and it works pretty good. The problem is that it scrolls away when you scroll in the table. It should stick to the top.

Do I need to embed this modal UITableViewController in a UINavigationController as well to get the "sticky top bar"?

What's the preferred way of doing this? Just embed using the storyboard or just create one "on the fly" in the prepareForSegue method?

**EDIT**

I ended up just embedding the modal UITableViewControllers in UINavigationControllers using Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need a `UINavigationController` that contains the `UITableViewController` to get what you aim for.

Personally, I would prefer creating it "on the fly" as you call it. But that is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you. I used the Storyboard though :)

Comment: How did you add the toolbar though?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it in the storyboard is to have your modal view controller be a UIViewController rather than a UITableViewController. Add a view controller, then drag in a tool bar, and position it at the top. Then add a table view to take up the rest of the space below the tool bar. This will work correctly without scrolling with the table view.

Comment: Tried it but I'm using static tables (should have written that in my original question) and it seems to require a UITableViewController

Comment: @Linus, so did you get it to work in the storyboard? If so, you should post your solution as an answer to help anyone else who tries to do this.

Comment: I just used a UINavigationController as per my comment to the accepted answer. Edited my first question with the solution now.